# Pagination formatting in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, pagination

So i was looking into Pagination dependency in ReactJS. My code is working fine but the formatting of pagination is quite out of order. How can i improve my pagination outlook. It's currently showing as bullets

```
<Pagination
  activePage={this.state.activePage}
  itemsCountPerPage={18}
  totalItemsCount={this.state.totalBooks}
  pageRangeDisplayed={3}
  onChange={this.handlePageChange} />
```

It's showing in the browser as the attached image[image: this what my browser is showing. I don't want to add a new bootstrap file.]

Comment: Style it properly.

Comment: How ?? that's what im asking

Comment: what is the name of the package ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination   ->> this is the link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the Mobile Stepper of material-ui helpful in this case. I imported 
`import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';` 
I just had to make a simple `updatePage(i)` function that took +1 or -1 depending upon the next or previous page and corresponding any other function calls can be done in update page function. Hence easily pagination can be done and new information can be rendered accordingly. Although this is not the exact correct method, but it helped me with my functionality.

```
<MobileStepper steps='5' position='static' activeStep='1' nextButton={<Button size='small' onClick={this.updatePage.bind(this,1)}/>Next</Button>} backButton={ <Button size='small' onClick={this.updatePage.bind(this,-1)} disabled={this.props.match.params.pageNo <= 1}>Prev</Button>} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `ul { display: flex;}`
in your css file it will show horizontally. Check also  other div should not overlap

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `react-js-pagination`:

> The component comes with no built-in styles. HTML layout compatible with Bootstrap pagination stylesheets.

So if you are using Bootstrap, it should just work.

If not the package provide some props to set classes to different elements, and then you should style them :

> innerClass, activeClass, activeLinkClass, itemClass, itemClassFirst, itemClassPrev, itemClassNext, itemClassLast ...

Comment: Im not familiar with bootstrap can you help me with this particular code of how i can format it

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework, you can start by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to acquire some notion about DOM scaffolding and CSS:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
 display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #999;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a.active {
 color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" /><</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active"/>1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" />2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" />></a></li>
</ul>
```